# unable to open(/proc/$pid/ns/{namespace_files})

Tags: c++, file-read, linux-namespaces

I've to join a process to a new namespace, so i'm extracting the namespace fd's of a process, so that it can call setns on those fd's.

But the problem is all returned fd's are -1s.

I did this:

```
cout<<mnt<<"\n"; // prints /proc/4563/ns/mnt
int mnt_fd =  open(mnt, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);      
cout<<mnt_fd<<" \n"; // prints -1


cout<<net<<"\n"; // prints /proc/4563/ns/net
int net_fd =  open(net, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);          
cout<<net_fd<<" \n"; //prints -1

cout<<pid<<"\n"; // prints /proc/4563/ns/pid
int pid_fd =  open(pid, O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC);
cout<<pid_fd<<" \n"; // prints -1
```

`pid`, `mnt`, `net` are declared paths.
How can i resolve this ?

**EDIT1**: on printing stderror it says `permission denied`
On doing `sudo chmod 755` on whole proc filesystem it prints `operation not permitted`

**EDIT2**: I was doing the mistake the of not compiling and running the executable with sudo. This time it can open the fds and returned fds are all positive. Similar to above i've opened other namespace fds too like usr_fd to join user namespace, ipc_fd to join ipc namespace and uts_fd to join uts namespace of the target process, but when doing `setns` on `userfd` it is givng error of `Invalid argument`.
Below is the code i've written to join namespaces.

```
pid_t cpid = fork();
    if(cpid == 0){
       if (setns(pid_fd, 0) == -1)        /* Join pid namespace */
           cout<<"joining pid "<<strerror(errno);
       if (setns(uts_fd, 0) == -1)        /* Join uts namespace */
           cout<<"joining uts "<<strerror(errno);
       if (setns(ipc_fd, 0) == -1)        /* Join pic namespace */
           cout<<"joining ipc "<<strerror(errno);
       if (setns(usr_fd, 0) == -1)        /* Join usr namespace */
           cout<<"joining usr "<<strerror(errno);
       if (setns(net_fd, 0) == -1)        /* Join net namespace */
           cout<<"joining net "<<strerror(errno);
       if (setns(mnt_fd, 0) == -1)        /* Join mnt namespace */
           cout<<"joining mnt "<<strerror(errno);

        char *argv[] = { "sudo ./mycode",NULL };
        execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);                                                                                        
    }
```

I wanted the child process to execute the getcode program in that namespace but it is not doing so? If it is the wrong way to do this, then how can the child run a program in that namespace?

mycode.cpp

```
int main() {
  
  printf("I am child process %d of parent %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
  while (true) {
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT3**: However replacing below line:

```
char *argv[] = { "sudo ./mycode",NULL };
execve(argv[0], argv, NULL);
```

with this

```
    char *argv[] = {"ps", NULL};  
    execvp(argv[0], &argv[0]);
```

works.

Comment: Do you have the required permissions to open the paths?  What happens if you do `ls /proc/4563/ns/mnt` at the command line?

Comment: what does errno say?

Comment: @G.M. It says permission denied

Comment: @user253751 yes the errno also says permission denied, what i can do now?

Comment: changing permission also not helping. on doing sudo chmod 755 on the whole proc filesystem, it says operation not permitted

Comment: Does process 4563 belong to the same user as the one your program belongs to?

Comment: @user253751 How can i identify that? It's uid is 0 from host.

Comment: @user253751 The userid on the terminal is 1000 and loginuid of the 4563 is also 1000

Comment: Are you sure, that the files contain the information you want to get? On my system these 'files' are links to something like 'mnt:[4026531840]' , which looks like some broken or non-filesystem link.

Comment: @gerum They are special files. Similar to /proc/whatever/fd/whatever, which you can open even if they look like broken symlinks

Comment: I believe you should be using dedicated API, not some custom file-like manipulations: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setns.2.html

Comment: @gerum yes it is links to those namespaces which the current process has to join. In general any process can join to that namespace using those links.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need the [`CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability to access namespace references](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559723) (and several other things) inside the `/proc` process filesystem, including the namespace-related subparts coming from the [nsfs namespace filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559723) inside procfs. Here, `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` and `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` are only part of the game. Depending on your exact deployment they might be needed, when running as non-UID0 with limited capabilities.

Running as root usually grants you all capabilities, including `CAP_SYS_PTRACE`. A non-UID0 process can be granted access by giving it the bounded, permitted, and not least effective `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability (-ies).

One way to do this is to set the ("POSIX") file capabilities using the `setcap` CLI tool. As usual, with great power comes great responsibility, so make sure to properly harden your binary so it cannot be used as a trampoline to gain forbidden system access.